# Problem with tags/user feeds

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Atom XML feeds malformed - redundant empty line?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144771/atom-xml-feeds-malformed-redundant-empty-line)

My SO tags feed has stopped working. When I open the url (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=perl+or+git) in a browser it suggests me to save the file.

Comment: Same problem with user feeds http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/244297

Comment: Possibly related to [RSS XML malformed - redundant empty line?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144771)

Comment: With [Atom XML feeds malformed - redundant empty line?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144771) solved, are your feeds now working again?

Comment: @Martijn no, at the moment (you can try it yourself)

Comment: Indeed, the empty first line is back again. I've poked the SE dev who fixed it last time.