# Atom XML feeds malformed - redundant empty line?

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, xml

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/delphi

Trying to read it in Opera i was "greeted" with "1st line should be XML declaration" error.

I tried few validators:

- Same error on  http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%2Fdelphi
- Probably related error on http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/?lang=en&url=https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/delphi
- NETWORK_ERROR at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp (well, hopefully it does not CAUSE it :-) )

Comment: No, it is not. First line is empty. Tried with the newest FF.

Comment: and it is exactly redundant 4 me.
Redundant as line, not as empty one.

English is not my native, sorry.

Comment: @Arioch'The: that comment was directed at a comment of mine, where I claimed the XML feed does start with a XML declaration. I've since retracted that comment to make it a full post below.

Comment: Well, that's why it is baf idea to delete comments :-)
Though i sometimes do it myself :-)

Comment: The problem is back again today.

Comment: And fixed again: [Feeds have stopped working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147058)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recent upgrade introduced a blank line above the xml declaration, breaking our feeds.

This has been fixed and we've already deployed the change.  Feeds should be working correctly now.

Comment: This continues to be broken for filtered feeds from http://stackexchange.com/filters. When is the fix likely to be deployed?  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145297/67392.

Comment: Rebecca, the problem is back again today, I've retested and the feeds are once more starting with a `\r\n` line. Doesn't the SE codebase have continuous integration tests? :-P

Comment: And it's fixed again: [Feeds have stopped working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147058)

Answer (score 12):

I can confirm there is a validation error in the feed:

```py
>>> import urllib2
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/delphi').read()
>>> data[:10]
'\r\n<?xml ve'
```

There is a CRLF (carriage-return + newline) combo before the `<?xml .. ?>` declaration statement, and the [XML 1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog) only allows for whitespace *after* that declaration:

> `prolog      ::=      XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?`

where `Misc*` is a comment, a processing instruction or whitespace. Without the CRLF the feed is otherwise valid.

CRLF normally delimits HTTP headers, so I suspect the header generation for feeds has a bug where one CRLF is appended too many to the header output.

Comment: or maybe some empty header getsadded at the end, if no sanity check catches it...

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yeah, that would be one reason for such a bug.

Comment: Hehe, someone downvoted to disagree. What, may I ask, is there to disagree? That adding a `CRLF` to the start of a XML document doesn't make it malformed?

Comment: maybe that since that is bug, the real answer would be fixing the code ? i just don't know how bugs are tracked on SO :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: Sure, but I don't have the code access to make that fix. That's up to the StackExchange devs. We can help by diagnosing the exact nature of said bug though.

Comment: Then sorry, no green V to You ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: Oh dear, not sure if I can live with that! :-P