# RSS feed doesn't work in Thunderbird because of stray newline

Tags: bug, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Atom XML feeds malformed - redundant empty line?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144771/atom-xml-feeds-malformed-redundant-empty-line)

The RSS feed starts with a carriage return, which prevents Thunderbird from parsing the file. Can it be removed?