# Filtered Question Atom Feed Is Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, atom, tag-filters

The feeds from https://stackexchange.com/filters (or at least the three I have setup) have just stopped working.

Appears there is some extra whitespace before the XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"...`): this is not allowed by XML. Thus feed readers reject it.

Edit: Looks like it was working until shortly after 16:00BST (15:00UTC).

Comment: Related: [Atom XML feeds malformed - redundant empty line?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144771/atom-xml-feeds-malformed-redundant-empty-line) (same bug, different feed)

Comment: @TheElementofMagic does appear to be the same bug; but that one has been fixed and this continues to be broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right – the white space in our feeds was unintentionally shifted around when we upgraded to v2 of the Razor view engine. It's fixed now.

Comment: And now my feed reader is happier. Thanks.