# Feeds have stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

An extraneous line feed at the start of the page has stopped the feeds working properly. For example,  I put https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds into a [Feed Validator](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check?url=https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds) and it shows:

```
Sorry
This feed does not validate.

line 2, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:2:0: xml declaration not at start of external entity [help]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds

1.  
2. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

This happened for a while last month until the line feed was removed..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we broke it. Again. Hint for .NET/MVC folks - never leave whitespace lines in your `_ViewStart.cshtml` ;p

Deploying now.

Comment: You should even put a big [warning comment in there](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml#5) just in case people forget! ;)

Comment: @Tim the funny thing is, that file is actually an old copy of our stackoverflow one, and I wrote that very comment. What I *forgot* to say in that comment is "or above". Some `@using ...` directives got added *above* that `@{ ... }` block, and a blank line ;(

Comment: You need automated regression tests for this.. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I was poking fun, heheh (although I didn't know that you specifically had written it). Ahhh I see. Pesky return key.

Comment: Many thanks for fixing the problem so quickly.

Comment: @stevem we try to always be ready-and-willing to press the big "deploy" button. Fortune favors the brave.